# eth-brownie 'Accounts' object has no attribute 'connect_to_clef'

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity

From brownie console if I enter **accounts.connect_to_clef()** I get the error **'Accounts' object has no attribute 'connect_to_clef'**  other accounts functions pop up if i just type accounts. and wait for the menu.  This is a function in the docs and also in accounts.py on the master branch.

Using pipx I've tried reinstalling, installing a specific commit (the most recent), downloading the zip of the files and installing from that and none of them work.  How do I get this function to work?